# How to change the scrolling direction

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like to change the direction of scroll in opposite direction for specific column. I tried searching google, but i don't find any solution. To give an example, take this...

jFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yLHeC/1/

There are three columns,

left, center, right. Each column height is 5000px. The center column has negative margin of 4500px. Now when user scroll, left and right should be as usual, but the center should scroll from bottom to top. Hope you got it.

Example site : http://www.ballantyne.it/

```
.left{
height:5000px;
}

.center{
height:5000px;
margin-top:-4500px;
}

.right{
height:5000px;
}
```

Comment: How can you scroll invisible content?

Comment: Check this site for example - http://www.ballantyne.it/

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea from a usability perspective?  Users expect scrolling to behave in a specific way, its not usually a good idea to change that.  Scrolling on that sample site makes me nauseous.

Comment: If you check their source you should see that the code is handled with javascript, you will not achieve this only with css and html. I can't see any javascript in your jsfiddle.

Comment: check out my edited answer, it provides javascript that you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a container for the center column, set it's overflow to hidden, height to window's height and then using `$(window).scroll()` event append `$(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop()` to the center column - this should work for you

EDIT: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/yLHeC/30/ and explanation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var CONSTANT_OFFSET = -200; // starting position
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       $('.center').css('margin-top', CONSTANT_OFFSET + $(this).scrollTop()*2 + 'px'); 
    }).scroll();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my example the scroll position is locked to the height of the adjacent column so the amount of movement is a calculation of the ratio and therefore precise.

http://jsfiddle.net/kuxi/xNSTb/

```
$('.right').scrollTop(
    ($('.right .content').height() - $(window).height())
    *
    ( 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / ($('.left .content').height() - $(window).height()))
);
```